# Excel condition formatting of an Nth tab at the end of N records which is equal to the SUM of N number of records

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a requirement where i need to conditional format a tab called 'Totals' at the end of n rows, where the result should be the SUM of all n rows in 'Cost' column

For example, as you can see below, the only thing i am sure of is the first column of the Cost is j9. and everything else like, number of records for Cost and where does the tab Totals start is unclear as the ETL process might insert n records.  so unsure, where it is going to be, but i need the Totals tab in exactly at the place where the nth record end and the net result  of it should be SUM(J9:Jn) something like this.

[image: requirement]

I've tried OFFSET and other sorts of stuff, but couldn't find any solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared, beforehand, to enter the word *Totals* in the appropriate cell then the formula below will calculate the summation of the costs (being the total of the cells in column J **only** below the word *Cost* and above the word *Totals*):
[image: Screenshot of suggested formula]

Comment: Thank you for your response, problem is I am not sure yet where the TOTALS goes in which appropriate cell since the records changes dynamically for each run.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using, and is your data coming in from Power Query ?